# Azure Functions scaling and concurrency using Queue triggers and functionAppScaleLimit on the Consumption Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-queues

I have an Azure Function app on the Linux Consumption Plan that has two queue triggers. Both queue triggers have the `batchSize` parameter set to `1` because they can both use about 500 MB of memory each and I don't want to exceed the 1.5GB memory limit, so they should only be allowed to pick up one message at a time.

If I want to allow both of these queue triggers to run concurrently, but don't want them to scale beyond that, is setting the `functionAppScaleLimit` to `2` enough to achieve that?

**Edit: added new examples, thank you @Hury Shen for providing the framework for these examples**

Please see @Hury Shen's answer below for more details. I've tested three queue trigger scenarios. All use the following legend:
[image]

**QueueTrigger with no `functionAppScaleLimit`**
[image]

**QueueTrigger with `functionAppScaleLimit` set to `2`**
[image]
**QueueTrigger with `functionAppScaleLimit` set to `1`**
[image]

For now, I think I'm going to stick with the last example, but in the future I think I can safely set my `functionAppScaleLimit` to `2` or `3` if I upgrade to the premium plan. I also am going to test two queue triggers that listen to different storage queues with a `functionAppScaleLimit` of `2`, but I suspect the safest thing for me to do is to create separate Azure Function apps for each queue trigger in that scenario.

**Edit 2: add examples for two queue triggers within one function app**

Here are the results when using two queue triggers within one Azure Function that are listening on two different storage queues. This is the legend for both queue triggers:
[image]

**Both queue triggers running concurrently with `functionAppScaleLimit` set to 2**
[image]
**Both queue triggers running concurrently with `functionAppScaleLimit` set to 1**
[image]

In the example where two queue triggers are running concurrently with `functionAppScaleLimit` set to `2` it looks like the scale limit is not working. Can someone from Microsoft please explain? There is no warning in the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#limit-scale-out) that this setting is in preview mode, yet we can clearly see that the Azure Function is scaling out to 4 instances when the limit is set to 2. In the following example, it looks like the limit is being respected, but the functionality is not what I want and we still see the waiting that is present in @Hury Shen's answer.

**Conclusion**
To limit concurrency and control scaling in Azure Functions with queue triggers, you must limit your Azure Function to use one queue trigger per function app and use the `batchSize` and `functionAppScaleLimit` settings. You will encounter race conditions and waiting that may lead to timeouts if you use more than one queue trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to set `functionAppScaleLimit` to `2`. But there are some mechanisms about consumption plan you need to know. I test it in my side with `batchSize` as `1` and set `functionAppScaleLimit` to `2`(I set `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` as `2` in "**Application settings**" of function app instead of set `functionAppScaleLimit`, they are same). And I test with the code below:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import time

def main(msg: func.QueueMessage) -> None:
    logging.info('=========sleep start')
    time.sleep(30)
    logging.info('=========sleep end')
    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

Then I add message to the queue, I sent 10 messages: `111`, `222`, `333`, `444`, `555`, `666`, `777`, `888`, `999`, `000`, I sent them one by one. The function was triggered success and after a few minutes, we can see the logs in "**Monitor**". Click one of the log in "**Monitor**", we can see the logs show as:
[image]

I use 4 red boxes on the right of the screenshot above, I named each of the four logs as "**s1**", "**s2**", "**s3**", "**s4**"(step 1-4). And summarize the logs in excel for your reference:
[image]

I make cells from "**s2**" to "**s4**" as yellow because this period of time refer to the execution time of the function task.

**According the screenshot of excel, we can infer the following points**:

**1.** The maximum number of instances can only be extended to 2 because we can find it doesn't exist more than two yellow cells in each line of the excel table. **So the function can not scale beyond 2 instances as you mentioned in your question.**

**2.** You want  to allow both of these queue triggers to run concurrently, it can be implemented. **But the instances will be scale out by mechanism of consumption.** In simple terms, when one function instance be triggered by one message and hasn't completed the task, and now another message come in, it can not ensure another instance be used. The second message might be waiting on the first instance. **We can not control whether another instance is enabled or not**.

===============================**Update**==============================

As I'm not so clear about your description, I'm not sure how many storage queues you want to listen to and how many function apps and QueueTrigger functions you created in your side. I summarize my test result as below for your reference:

**1.** For your question about `would the Maximum Burst you described on the premium plan behave differently than this ?` I think if we choose premium plan, the instances will also be scale out with same mechanism of consumption plan.

**2.** If you have two storage queues need to be listen to, of course we should create two QueueTrigger functions to listen to each storage queue.

**3.** If you just have one storage queue need to be listen to, I test with three cases(I set max scale instances as 2 in all of three cases):

A) Create **one** QueueTrigger function in **one** function app to listen to **one** storage queue. This is what I test in my original answer, the excel table shows us the instances will scale out by mechanism of consumption plan and we can not control it.

B) Create **two** QueueTrigger functions in **one** function app to listen to **same** storage queue. The result is almost same with case A, we can not control how many instances be used to deal with the messages.

C) Create **two** function apps and create **a** QueueTrigger function in **each of** function app to listen to **same** storage queue. The result also similar to case A and B, the difference is the max instances can be scaled to 4 because I created two function apps(both of them can scale to 2 instances).

So in a word, I think all of the three cases are similar. Although we choose case 3, create two function apps with one QueueTrigger function in each of them. **We also can not make sure the second message be deal with immediately, it still may be processed to first instance and wait for frist instance complete deal with the first message.**

**So the answer for your current question in this post** `is setting the functionAppScaleLimit to 2 enough to achieve that?` **is: If you want both of instances be enabled to run concurrently, we can't make sure of it. If you just want two instances to deal with the messages, the answer is yes.**

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. Are both of the queue triggers in your example listening on the same queue? My example would be for separate queues and then maybe Azure Functions would be able to ensure another instance is being used?

Comment: And would the `Maximum Burst` you described on the premium plan behave differently than this? This solution wouldn't work for me because each instance can take about 5 minutes and I can't afford to lose that time while it waits for other instances to finish.

Comment: maybe setting `newBatchThreshold` to `0` would fix the issue as well?

Comment: I tested your process using two queues and a `newBatchThreshold` of `0` and the issue is still there because I see some of the queue triggers took over 60 seconds to execute. Do you think there is any solution here? Or do I have to create a completely separate Azure Function for each queue or upgrade to the premium plan?

Comment: I think my best bet is to use two separate Azure Function apps that will listen to each individual queue to make sure the waiting in your example doesn't happen. Then in the future I can upgrade both plans to premium and use `Maximum Burst` if I need it?

Comment: Hi @ddx I will do more test and then reply you. And may I confirm that if there are two queues of storage to need to listen to ? I mean two queue storage `queue1` and `queue2`. Or you just have one queue storage, but you have two(or more than two) clients send messages to the same queue storage ?

Comment: @ddx And you mentioned that `I have an Azure Function app on the Linux Consumption Plan that has two queue triggers` and `I think my best bet is to use two separate Azure Function apps`. May I know if you create two queue trigger function in one function app ? Or you create two function apps, and create a queue trigger function in each of the function app ?

Comment: Hi @ddx Please refer to "Update" of my answer. That is all of my test result.

Comment: I have two separate storage queues. I now think that I need to create two separate function apps to listen to each queue because I want the messages to be processed sequentially without the race conditions and waiting in your example. When I set `batchSize` to `1` and `functionAppScaleLimit` to `1` I do not see the behavior in your example and it works like I expect it to. Are you sure your `batchSize` is set to `1` in your example?

Comment: Now my concern is, when my messages start to grow and I need to upgrade to the premium plan, how can I achieve concurrency without the waiting behavior in your example?

Comment: My original idea was to use two queue storage `queue1` and `queue2` that listen on different storage queues, but then I noticed behavior similar to your example (waiting). I think if I create two distinct function apps I can achieve true sequential ordering by setting `batchSize` to `1` and `functionAppScaleLimit` to `1`.

Comment: please see my updated examples. I suspect that either `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` is not working the same as `functionAppScaleLimit` or you didn't have the `batchSize` parameter set to `1`. In my examples, it looks like the scale limit is behaving exactly how I would expect/want it to.

Comment: Hi @ddx I did not set `functionAppScaleLimit` or `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to `1`. In all of my test, I set `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to `2`. And set `batchSize` to `1` in all of test.

Comment: @ddx For your question about why the function can scale out to 4 instances, I think you can [raise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) a support ticket on azure portal to ask azure support team for help. They can see your backend log and know the details of scale out mechanism.

Comment: I think it might be because I temporarily disabled the azure function and loaded the queue with 10 messages. When I tested again only doing one message at a time the scaling happened as expected with only 2 running at a time.